# How to print n numbers of * using a loop in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to create a program which prints 6 * 10 times using a for loop, but it does not work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, num1 = 60, num2;
    num2 = 60 / 10;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        printf("%d* \n", num2);
    }
}
```

This prints `6*` ten times, but I want to print 6 six 10 times like this

```
******
******
******
......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is took a loop and print same int with a star.

If you need to print `2D` grid, you have to use nested loop.

Like this

```
int i, j, num1 = 60, num2;
num2 = 60 / 10;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < num2; j++)
        printf("*");
    printf("\n");
}
```

<kbd>**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Hv7Ze3)**</kbd>

Comment: Sure, just waiting for 5 more minute to pass.

Comment: You could use `putchar('*');` and `putchar('\n');` instead of using a `printf()` sledgehammer to do the job.